# Best practice where to load Dojo from

Tags: dojo

I'm not a Dojo developer and don't need to work with it at all. But what I have to do is do the integration with Dojo widget using the jQuery. I already figured out how to do this ([another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284745/load-and-use-dojo-widget-from-jquery)), but for that purpose I've downloaded the Dojo toolkit on my side and load it from there. Toolkit is pretty heavy and contains a lot of files, so I was thinking if I really need it for so simple task, is it really necessary to host Dojo on my side or it's better to include it to the page's source and load it from some other place? I was thinking about to load it from here: http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.8.3/dojo-release-1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js or from here http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js but just not sure is it a good idea at all? What is the best practice here?

Dojo-experts, what do you say about it?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I try to avoid CDN because I:

- typically write "internal" apps for corporate customers and I prefer
  loading everything from their internal servers rather than fetching
  dependencies over the web -- which could induce perceived or real
  security concerns on their part
- prefer creating my own build which includes my "widgets"
- want to have a self-contained build that can be packaged with Phonegap and run without network access

There is a tiny "nano" version of the library that will give you the AMD loader: http://dojotoolkit.org/features. You can use that to load your jQuery modules and add only the Dojo modules that you need.

I found this article helpful as it addresses specifically the problem of creating a compact build: http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2012/06/11/dgrid-and-dojo-nano-build/. Here they load dGrid which is just an another module. But you can apply the concept to your loading of jQuery modules.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Frederic. Checked the links that you provided and looks like creating compact build is advanced level task... I don't want to spend much time on it right now, maybe later. I tried to load Dojo from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js but for some reasons it doesn't work... it can't load dependent modules (dojo.io.scripts in my case). I suspect that did some wrong dojo configuration but don't know what exactly. I use the next baseUrl: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo", do you know is it right one?

Comment: I believe that you have the right one, it's listed here: http://dojotoolkit.org/download/. But "dojo.io.scripts" appears to be deprecated. The equivalent module name is: "dojo/request/script"; this will help you with syntax if needed: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/request/script.html#dojo-request-script

Answer (score 1):

I started my Dojo development using the CDN and a local copy of the toolkit for development.

Dojo uses AMD module loaders, that are like a c "include" or c# "using". This means that only the functions you need are load into the app/page.

As I learned more about dojo, I learned to use the build system that pre fetches the Dojo modules (js files) into a single compressed file for you to distribute with your app. This however is delivered from you server not a public CDN.

In summary, my feeling is: CDN for quick development, Build System for performance

AMD https://dojotoolkit.org/blog/learn-more-about-amd

Build http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/build/

Web Builder at dojotoolkit.org/blog/introducing-the-new-dojo-web-builder (limeted to 2 links)